# Rails: pass an array to a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to figure out how to let a user enter multiple "skills" in a text area separated by comma's and then have those skills turned into an array that feeds into a scope one at a time.

Also on my index view I'm listing the skills in the array so that when a user clicks on one it will actually remove that skill as a filter.

The issues that i'm having are 
1) not sure I'm doing the array correctly the way i have it now

2) in the index view when you click on just one skill to remove, all skills are removed.

in my form

```
    <p>
      <%= label_tag(:sk, "Skills:") %>
      <%= text_area_tag :sk, params[:sk], placeholder: "Enter skills", class: "form-control" %>
    </p>
```

in my controllers index action

```
  # filters on the users skills
  if params[:sk].present? 

    @skills_list = params[:sk].split(",")
    @skills_list = @skills_list.to_a

    @skills_list.each do |skill|

    @users = @users.by_skills_array(skill)
    end
  end
```

in my user model I call the scope (The skill model is separate but belongs_to the user model so that's why i'm doing the join).

```
  scope :by_skills_array, -> (skill) { joins(:skills).distinct.where( 'skills.name LIKE ?', "%#{skill}%" ) }
```

in my index I'm doing

```
  <% if params[:sk].present? %>

    <% @skills_list.each do |skill|  %>

        <%= link_to  users_path( c: params[:c], ex: params[:ex], s: params[:s], lang: params[:lang], cert: params[:cert], 
                                 u: params[:u], relo: params[:relo], ed: params[:ed], maj: params[:maj], job: params[:job] ) , class: "btn btn-default" do %>
          <i class="fa fa-times"></i> <%= "#{skill}" %>
        <% end %>   


    <% end %>

  <% end %>
```

here's the output

[image]

Comment: In the index action, what are you trying to achieve? Get list of users with the skills indicated? And how is `skills_list` populated? `Skill.all`?

Comment: yes I'm trying to get a list of users that have particular skills.  In the index action i'm doing @users = User.all  and then applying the if statements.  the skills_list is populated from the view by passing params[:sk] to it.  So params[:sk] will have "A, B, C" from the form that was submitted.

Comment: But inside the loop `@users = @users.by_skills_array(skill)` this will just assign @users and @users will be set to the users who have the last skill. Bit out of context but worth noting.

Comment: good point.  I guess I'm looking for a way to have all the search terms for skills applied to users.  And then be able to remove them one at a time and have the results adjust.  So if the user has skill A and skill B their profile shows up in the index and then if I remove skill A and keep skill B then additional users may show up that only have skill B.

Comment: Do you know how to do what you want in SQL? I often find that's a good place to start... have a play around in your SQL manager (eg `psql`) with some sample data and try to get a SQL query that does what you want (ie will find the set of users where they have a given set of skills). Then we can help you convert that to a nice `arel` statement for you.

Comment: Possibly start by not allowing a `LIKE` but only exact-matching... (for simplicity's sake?)

Comment: I'd suggest you have a look at https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on. They way you're storing and trying to access the skills is what that plugin is doing for years and is actively maintained. Usage will be much cleaner that way. and you could keep you textarea and just split them into distinct tags on edits.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi The in-loop scoping should not be a problem. You have `@users` variable, that contains all users (eg. `Users.all`), which you then scope for the first time ( `@users = @users.by_skill_array(skill1)` ), assigning it to variable @users again. Now you have `@users` scoped by first skill. Scoping with second skill ( `@users = @users.by_skill_array(skill2)` ) takes the variable (which now contains only the relevant users for first skill, not all users) and scopes it again. Hence this is useable approach, not nonsense.

Comment: @Jacob, you are right, I must have not been paying attention while posting that comment. @Scott, sorry about that `@users = @users.by_skills_array(skill)` will work as it's expected to be.